# UIGestureRecognizer Determine Tap

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I followed this answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12481177/2575115

but I get an error "Expected Expression". What am I doing wrong?

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch;
{
    BOOL shouldReceiveTouch = YES;

    if (gestureRecognizer == tap) { //Expected Expression
        shouldReceiveTouch = (touch.view == _shownImage);
    }
    return shouldReceiveTouch;
}
```

Comment: What is `tap` here?, it seems it is undefined.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475250/how-to-compare-the-types-of-gestures-on-ios) it might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check the UIGestureRecognizer class

```
-(BOOL) gestureRecognizer: (UIGestureRecognize *) gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer: (UIGestureRecognizer *) otherGestureRecognizer {
if ([gestureRecognizer isMemberOfClass: [UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {

shouldReceiveTouch = (touch.view == _shownImage);    

     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if your `tap(UITapGestureRecognizer)` gesture is a member of `UIGestureRecognizer` by `isMemberOfClass`.

```
-(BOOL) gestureRecognizer: (UIGestureRecognize *) gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer: (UIGestureRecognizer *) otherGestureRecognizer {
    if ([gestureRecognizer isMemberOfClass: [tap class]]) {// please check this one
    }
   }
```