# Get reference of gesture recognizer in xib not using IBOutlet

Tags: ios, xib, gesture

I create a single tap and double tap gesture recognizer in a xib file, and I want to access it in a category, but the Referring Outlet of xib in property and it cannot be inserted in a category, can I use code to access gesture recognizer reference in function `viewDidLoad`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. A view keeps a list of its Gesture Recognizers so you just need to loop through them.

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in self.gestureRecognizers)
{
    // You need a way to identify it here
}
```

In this case, if your category is extending a view controller, you just need to know which view contains the gesture recognizer you want.

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray<__kindof UIGestureRecognizer *> *gestureRecognizers;
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622542-gesturerecognizers?language=objc

Edit:

If your category is extending a ViewController change the loop to self.view.gestureRecognizers (or any other view that you attached it to)

Comment: self.gestureRecognizers what is this gestureRecognizers? And if I need to find single tap gesture what is the key to find it?

Comment: its a property all UIViews have. You have to identify it based on what other recognizers you have set. You can check each of its properties until you find the one that matches your criteria. (Number of taps, type, etc)

Comment: I find the gestureRecognizers thank you, and I still want to know if I want to detect whether the recognizer is a tapGesture which function should I use? I mean how to detect its type? Can you show the function?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475250/how-to-compare-the-types-of-gestures-on-ios

Comment: 'for (UIGestureRecognizer * recognizer in [self.pdfCustomView gestureRecognizers]) {
        if([recognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {
            if(recognizer.numberOfTapsRequired ==1) { '                                                      I write like this  but there is an error said Property numberOfTapsRequired not found on type "UIGestureRecognizer", do you know how to solve this?

Comment: You have to cast it first to "UITapGestureRecognizer" and check that its NOT null. Then if its not null it means that its a tap gesture recognizer and then you can call that property.